# function/selector to filter inputs by value

Tags: jquery

Is there a built-in function/selector in jQuery to filter the inputs by value?

I can create a custom selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    val: function(elem, index, match) {
       return $(elem).val() == match[3];
    }
});
```

and use it like this: `$("input:val('Some text')")`.

I was just wondering if something like this already exists or maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't look like there's a built-in solution. But for a one-off selector, [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is an option:

```js
$('input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() === 'Some text'; });
```

Comment: Do you know if it is faster than doing each() ?

Comment: @MartinZvarík ah sorry, never saw this comment. It's not faster, it still has to loop over everything.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
    $('input[value=someval]')
```

you can also chain it

```
    $('input[type=radio][value=someval]')
```

look [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

Comment: This will return the default(attribute) value, but I need the current value of the control.

Comment: The first will select all input with the value='someval'. This is a selector, it returns a collection of jquery objects. This "filters the inputs by value" as it returns only inputs with a certain value.

Comment: value='someval' will filter the controls by the initial value defined by "value" attribute. <input type="text" name="n" value="someval" />, if the user changes the text in the input box, ex to 'newval' the input[value=someval] will still select the node (at least in standards compliant browsers, ex FF), because the default value is still 'someval'. IE will filter against the current value which is not acording to HTML standard.

Comment: Ok, now i understand what you mean! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    val: function(elem, index, match) {
       return $.trim($(elem).val()) == $.trim(match[3]);
    }
});
```